# Jquery Closest getting Attributes of Elements of Parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a repetitive div structure

```
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="name" value="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="123">
  <span class="btns">
  <button name="btn_clr" class="clear" type="button" value="Clear"></button>
  </span> 
  </div>
```

in Jquery i have a onclick function for clear button as

```
$('.clear').bind("click", function (e){ 
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('input').each(function (index){                    
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

I want to clear out the values of input elements of Paret Class DIV but its not getting the INPUT elements in the each function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('.clear').bind("click", function (e){ 
   $(this).closest('.parent').find('input').each(function (index){
        $(this).val(''); // to clear the value
   });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wH9KQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.parent()` like

```
$('.clear').bind("click", function (e){ 
     $(this).closest('.btns').parent().find('input').each(function (index){                    
          console.log(this);
     });
});
```

Or even try like

```
$('.clear').bind("click", function (e){ 
     $(this).closest('.parent').find('input').each(function (index){                    
          console.log(this);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent` is the class value of the target element, so you need to use it with a class selector like `.parent`

```
$('.clear').bind("click", function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('input').each(function (index) {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```